# Adicionar Numero a Direita

Tags: vb.net

Hoje o meu select me retorna uma letra, A, B, C por exemplo. Gostaria de adicionar dois zeros a direita da letra, como posso fazer isso?

Exemplo de retorno:

"A"

Como gostaria que ficasse

"00A"

Comment: Qual select? É SQL?